# How to set 'reload:true' state with ui-router $stateProvider.state definition?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can reload my states using :

```
<a ui-sref="state" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">link</a>
```

but i wonder how to do this in my state definition, when i try to go from `/state/c/d` to `/state/a/b/c/d`

```
    $stateProvider.state('state', {
        name: 'state',
        url: '/state/{a:[0-9]+}/{b:[0-9]+}/{c:[0-9]+}/{d}',
        params: {
            a: {
                squash: true,
                value: null
            },
            b: {
                squash: true,
                value: null
            },
        },
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you don't. Options aren't part of state definitions. You pass those when you transition only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I want to do it. I will have to trigger a $state transition?